# thunderbolt3 to VGA not working

Tags: arch-linux

I have a (on windows working) thunderbolt3 to vga adapter connected to my linux notebook. I can't see anything on the screen and I do not get an error in `dmesg -w`.

The hardeware is:

```
hackbook-ng
    description: Notebook
    product: N13xWU (Not Applicable)
    vendor: TUXEDO
    version: Not Applicable
    serial: Not Applicable
    width: 4294967295 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Not Applicable sku=Not Applicable uuid=80FA5B53-3708-0000-0000-000000000000
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: N13xWU
       vendor: TUXEDO
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Applicable
       serial: Not Applicable
       slot: Not Applicable
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.05.11
          date: 02/09/2018
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 14
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
             product: BLS16G4S240FSD.16FBD
             vendor: 859B
             physical id: 0
             serial: 9150006A
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 19
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 1a
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 1b
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 8MiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1c
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3489MHz
          capacity: 4005MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 08
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: UHD Graphics 620
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:136 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:130 memory:dc210000-dc21ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.17.11-arch1 xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.17
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: SuYin USB2.0 RGBIR Camera
                   vendor: SuYin
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 0.11
                   serial: HF2066-P98B-OV09-REV0102
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 0.10
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.17.11-arch1 xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.17
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:dc22e000-dc22efff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:133 memory:dc22d000-dc22dfff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:131 memory:dc228000-dc229fff memory:dc22c000-dc22c0ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:dc22b000-dc22b7ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:c4000000-da0fffff ioport:a0000000(size=570425344)
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 02
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcieport
                resources: irq:125 memory:c4000000-da0fffff ioport:a0000000(size=570425344)
              *-pci:0
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:126 memory:da000000-da0fffff
              *-pci:1
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:127 memory:c4000000-d9efffff ioport:a0000000(size=570425344)
              *-pci:2
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:02.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:128 memory:d9f00000-d9ffffff
                 *-usb
                      description: USB controller
                      product: Intel Corporation
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:39:00.0
                      version: 02
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                      resources: irq:132 memory:d9f00000-d9f0ffff
                    *-usbhost:0
                         product: xHCI Host Controller
                         vendor: Linux 4.17.11-arch1 xhci-hcd
                         physical id: 0
                         bus info: usb@3
                         logical name: usb3
                         version: 4.17
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usbhost:1
                         product: xHCI Host Controller
                         vendor: Linux 4.17.11-arch1 xhci-hcd
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: usb@4
                         logical name: usb4
                         version: 4.17
                         capabilities: usb-3.10
                         configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:dc100000-dc1fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:129 memory:dc115000-dc115fff memory:dc100000-dc10ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.1
                logical name: enp58s0f1
                version: 12
                serial: 80:fa:5b:53:37:08
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dc114000-dc114fff memory:dc110000-dc113fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:dc000000-dc0fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
                logical name: wlp59s0
                version: 78
                serial: 9e:9b:42:1c:40:4e
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.17.11-arch1 firmware=36.e91976c0.0 ip=172.16.7.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:135 memory:dc000000-dc001fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:dc224000-dc227fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:137 memory:dc220000-dc223fff memory:dc200000-dc20ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:dc22a000-dc22a0ff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:03:df:0d:9b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                  118784  3
ccm                    20480  6
rfcomm                 86016  4
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink
xfrm_user              45056  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  3
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
xt_addrtype            16384  2
iptable_filter         16384  1
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nf_nat                 36864  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack          155648  7 xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_conntrack_netlink
br_netfilter           24576  0
bridge                188416  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
bnep                   24576  2
joydev                 24576  0
mousedev               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     57344  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   110592  1
snd_soc_skl           114688  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        73728  1 snd_soc_skl
vfat                   24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    86016  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  1 snd_soc_skl
fat                    81920  1 vfat
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
arc4                   16384  2
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
ext4                  741376  1
snd_soc_core          290816  1 snd_soc_skl
intel_rapl             24576  0
uvcvideo              110592  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
iwlmvm                430080  0
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
kvm_intel             233472  0
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
jbd2                  126976  1 ext4
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  53248  0
i915                 2043904  25
fscrypto               32768  1 ext4
snd_hda_intel          45056  6
mac80211              925696  1 iwlmvm
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
kvm                   729088  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec         151552  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
videodev              208896  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
iwlwifi               327680  1 iwlmvm
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
drm_kms_helper        200704  1 i915
btintel                24576  1 btusb
snd_hda_core           94208  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_skl
media                  45056  2 videodev,uvcvideo
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
pcbc                   16384  0
bluetooth             638976  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_pcm               135168  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
drm                   471040  16 drm_kms_helper,i915
cfg80211              778240  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
aesni_intel           200704  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              36864  1 snd_pcm
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
cryptd                 28672  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
snd                    98304  22 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
intel_cstate           16384  0
psmouse               167936  0
intel_uncore          131072  0
intel_gtt              24576  1 i915
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
r8169                  94208  0
agpgart                49152  2 intel_gtt,drm
tpm_tis                16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
led_class              16384  2 input_leds,iwlmvm
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 45056  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
rfkill                 28672  8 bluetooth,cfg80211
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
mii                    16384  1 r8169
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei                   106496  1 mei_me
i2c_i801               32768  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
tpm                    65536  3 tpm_tis,tpm_crb,tpm_tis_core
shpchp                 40960  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
wmi                    28672  1 intel_wmi_thunderbolt
evdev                  20480  13
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
rng_core               16384  1 tpm
rtc_cmos               24576  1
battery                24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
ac                     16384  0
pcc_cpufreq            16384  0
vboxpci                28672  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             32768  0
vboxdrv               487424  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
crypto_user            16384  0
ip_tables              28672  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               45056  5 xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_addrtype,ip_tables
btrfs                1372160  1
libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs
crc32c_generic         16384  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
zstd_decompress        81920  1 btrfs
zstd_compress         184320  1 btrfs
xxhash                 16384  2 zstd_compress,zstd_decompress
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   139264  2 usbhid,hid_generic
raid6_pq              122880  1 btrfs
sd_mod                 61440  5
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
serio_raw              16384  0
mmc_core              172032  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
atkbd                  32768  0
libps2                 16384  2 atkbd,psmouse
ahci                   40960  4
xhci_pci               16384  0
libahci                40960  1 ahci
xhci_hcd              266240  1 xhci_pci
libata                278528  2 libahci,ahci
usbcore               294912  5 xhci_hcd,usbhid,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci
crc32c_intel           24576  3
scsi_mod              258048  2 sd_mod,libata
rtsx_pci               73728  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
i8042                  32768  0
serio                  28672  9 serio_raw,atkbd,psmouse,i8042
```

**Update1**

Linux hackbook-ng 4.17.11-arch1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jul 29 10:11:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distro: ArchLinux (no ArchLabs etc)

**Update2**

disabled the security of the thunderbolt port in the bios... no change in the problem

Output of dmesg after plug in:
https://pastebin.com/FgXDyLL8

**Update3**

```
lsmod | grep typec
typec_wcove            16384  0
tcpm                   61440  1 typec_wcove
typec_displayport      16384  0
typec_ucsi             36864  1 ucsi_acpi
typec                  45056  3 typec_displayport,typec_ucsi,tcpm
```

Comment: add update with kernel and make clear that it is arch

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ArchLinux has no version numbers known to me, as it is a rolling release. The kernel version is newer than 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

The `bcdDevice` value for USB root hubs in your pastebin output indicates your kernel version is 4.17.*.

The last line in the pastebin output indicates that an [USB Billboard Device](https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/09/26/what_s_the_role_ofb-FaDC) is getting detected.

If I've understood correctly, that indicates the device has one or more USB Type-C Alternate Modes (probably DisplayPort or indeed Thunderbolt) and the system failed to activate them.

There should be an USB Type-C Port Manager in your kernel: it's one of the new features of the kernel version 4.17. At least before kernel version 4.17, there used to be kernel modules named `typec`, `typec_ucsi` and `ucsi_acpi`, with possibly other `ucsi_<something>` modules for Macs and/or other non-PC hardware. I don't really know how Type-C port management is supposed to work in kernels 4.17 and above, but if those modules exist in your kernel version, you should probably try and load them.

The USB Type-C support is very much work in progress, and I think the next major version (4.18) includes some more bits and pieces of Type-C support.

If the converter is essentially a DisplayPort-to-VGA converter, it might appear as one of the outputs listed by the `xrandr` command once the DisplayPort Alternate Mode is successfully activated. But if it's a real Thunderbolt device, it would basically be an extra GPU for your system: it would appear in `lspci` much like an extra graphics card.

[This document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/typec.html) describes how the Type-C mode control should work.

Essentially, it looks like you should find a file named like `/sys/class/typec/port<number>/<alternate mode>/mode<number>/active` that corresponds to your adapter, and then make something like this happen (ideally, automatically as the device is detected):

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/typec/port<number>/<alternate mode>/mode<number>/active
```

If the `/sys/class/typec` directory is empty, you definitely don't have all the pieces for USB Type-C support up and running yet. And that is a pre-requisite for Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: the Modules are loaded with no change to sys/class/typec